# Fun mobile apps for teaching kids English?

Tags: english, children, software

My two 12 y/o Israeli boys are struggling with English at school, as the school English teaching system is incompetent. However as they are addicted to their Android smartphones I'd be happy to enroll them to a fun and worthy English course, in English. Willing to pay if it is a good one.

Duolingo, Memrise, and other apps do not teach English in English (nor in Hebrew). I know there are hundreds of courses out there, but finding the right one would take me a lifetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes I recommended `Speedy English Grammar -Basic ESL Course & Lessons` by `Wobble Monkey English` second one `3350+ English Grammar Practice` by `Buffalo Software` in PlayStore only and in AppStore I don't know.
hope it will works.

Answer (score 2):

Not a smartphone app, but desktop:

When my son was learning English (about 10 years old), I introduced him to computer game Civilization (available for free as "Freeciv" on Linux). There, different civilization advancement can have effects on your tribe (like inventing religion allows you to build a temple, which allows your city to grow bigger and still avoid unhappy citizens). So he was reading Civilopedia to know how to be better in the game.

Paid version of Civilization has 3 completely different rule sets, last one on different planet. Lots of reading! Also, tips&tricks forums provide lots of reading too. And game itself is infinite in it's variability, and good training for life (you really need to plan your resources).

Strategy/planning games with lots of rules and unit development, and with forums/wikipedias full of relevant (to the game/player ) information is just yet another example of improving the language by reading for pleasure.

Another trick which worked on my other son was public library with children encyclopedias (Eyewitness series, with lots of images) about interesting stuff like pirates, dinosaurs, romans, egyptians, war machines and stuff.

Not all games have to be first-person shooters.

Comment: Yes. I pretty much started with Starcraft and a book on Greek mythology.